# Android: Integrate google drive in app

Tags: android, google-drive-api, bad-request

I have been following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) to integrate google drive in my app. However error occurs when running the app.

The error:

```
The following error occured: 400 Bad Request
{
"code":400,
"errors":[{
"domain":"global",
"location":"fiels",
"locationType":"parameter",
"message": "Invalid field selection items",
"reason":"invalidParameter"
}],
"message":"Invalid field selection items"
}
```

When I debugged this code I found the code is not executing beyond:

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // Get a list of up to 10 files.
            List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
            FileList result = mService.files().list()
                 .setPageSize(10)
                 .setFields("nextPageToken, items(id, name)")
                 .execute();
```

Here is the next step from the code that I have used:

```
List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File> files = result.getFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : files) {
                    fileInfo.add(String.format("%s (%s)\n",
                            file.getName(),file.getId() ));
                }
            }
            return fileInfo;
        }
```

In the manifest I have defined:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and inside application in manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="99102****479" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
            android:value="99102****479" />
```

I don't know what the problem is. Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: Looking at your error log, it seems you had a typo- "location":"fiels", instead of "files" or "fields". Try to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same tutorial a couple of days ago and got same problem, some how they did not updated their tutorial since in this line:

```
    .setFields("nextPageToken, items(id, name)")
```

have to be changed to

```
    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
```

as they explain in the search for files [section](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

Hope this helps!